# How to create a button with python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

So I want to create a button that you can click on in python.

I am making a very simple game with the python turtle module.

here's my code `x` is the x position of the click and `y` is the y position of the click.

```py
screen = turtle.Screen() #for some context

def click(x, y):
    if (x <= 40 and x <= -40) and (y <= 20 and y <= -20):
        #code here


screen.onscreenclick(click)
```

I want it to do the run some code when i click in a specific area but
this code doesn't work for me.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: code `(x <= 40 and x <= -40)` can be reduced to `(x <= -40)` - probably you used wrong `<=` and you need `(x <= 40 and x >= -40)` or more readable `(-40 <= x <= 40)` The same problem is with `(y <= 20 and y <= -20)`

Comment: What do you mean _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: Maybe first use `print(x)` and `print( x <= 40 and x <= -40 )` to see what you get.

Comment: @acw1668 I mean that when I click in the area or in any area it won't register the click.

Comment: Add `print(x, y)` at the beginning of `click()` and see whether it is shown in the console when you click any area on the turtle screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a button in turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902849/how-can-i-create-a-button-in-turtle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach the problem a different way.  Don't draw a button with the turtle and try to determine if the user clicked *within* the drawing, make a button out of a turtle and do something when the user clicks *on* it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def click(x, y):
    button.hideturtle()
    button.write("Thank you!", align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()

button = Turtle()
button.shape('square')
button.shapesize(2, 4)
button.fillcolor('gray')
button.onclick(click)

screen.mainloop()
```

If you insist on doing it your way, then the equivalent code might be:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def click(x, y):
    if -40 <= x <= 40 and -20 <= y <= 20:
        turtle.write("Thank you!", align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.fillcolor('gray')
turtle.goto(-40, -20)

turtle.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    turtle.forward(80)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.goto(0, 30)

screen.onclick(click)
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had the same idea but for me the button must have text so i set the color of the button to black (the same as the background) but it would end up covering the text. I tried hiding the turtle with `turtle.ht` but then it wouldn't register my click