# How to make a turtle button

Tags: python, button, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Is there any function that can check where your mouse is when you use `onclick()`. So I click on a colored area for example and then something happens.

Comment: See: [How to create a button with python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765658/how-to-create-a-button-with-python-turtle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using on_screen_click(x, y)