# How to run a method in the background using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, class, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run a method in the background of python (a class that is constantly updated by messages from an aws server) and I'm using this as a template. Problem is, I can't get it to print('checkpoint') or print('bye'). It just keeps running the run(self). Why is that?

```
import threading
import time


class ThreadingExample(object):
    """ Threading example class
    The run() method will be started and it will run in the background
    until the application exits.
    """

    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        """ Constructor
        :type interval: int
        :param interval: Check interval, in seconds
        """
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()                                  # Start the execution

    def run(self):
        """ Method that runs forever """
        while True:
            # Do something
            print('Doing something imporant in the background')

            time.sleep(self.interval)

example = ThreadingExample()
time.sleep(3)
print('Checkpoint')
time.sleep(2)
print('Bye')
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Comment: could you show your output and your expected output. It seems to work in my python 2.7 environment output `Doing something imporant in the background
Doing something imporant in the background
Doing something imporant in the background
Checkpoint
Doing something imporant in the background
Doing something imporant in the background
Bye`

Comment: My expected output is exactly what you put but instead it just keeps repeating 'Doing something important in the background' until I interupt it

Comment: did you try running it through `cmd line` and not your interpreter like canopy , pycharm etc..

Comment: You should ensure the thread started before starting your loop

Comment: Why don't you use Python 3? Your use of `print` with a function syntax suggests it is Python 3 already, so you wouldn' even have to change anything.

Comment: Because I'm ssh'ing to an AWS and that's what they have installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code it works fine (python34, ubuntu14)

**with thread.daemon = True:**

```
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Checkpoint
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Bye
```

**with daemon = False:**

```
Doing something imporant in the background
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Checkpoint
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Bye
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
Doing something important in the background
...
```

Answer (score 0):

NEVER MIND I FIXED IT

Instead of

```
 thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
```

I had

```
 thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run(), args=())
```

I don't know why but those brackets made it run forever

Comment: when you write self.run() the function run is called from the current thread (and loops forever), -therefor you get stuck the in that call. no other thread will be created...