# Getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start' when trying to run a basic thread program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm new to threads and am executing a very basic thread example. The following is the program I'm trying to execute:

```
import os
import thread
import threading

def main():
    t1=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(3,))
    t2=thread.start_new_thread(prints,(5,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    #t1.join()
    #t2.join()

def prints(i):
    while(i>0):
        print "i="+str(i)+"\n"
        i=i-1

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

When I try and execute, I keep getting the following error (**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start'**):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
i=3
  File "thread_1.py", line 19, in <module>

    i=2

i=1
main()

i=5

i=4

i=3

i=2

i=1

  File "thread_1.py", line 8, in main
    t1.start()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start'
```

As can be seen from the output, both are getting executed but not the way I was expecting it to (which is interleaved prints or something like that). It seems more sequential too. How can I modify/correct my program to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`thread.start_new_thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) (boldface mine):

> Start a new thread and **return its identifier**.

So you are actually calling `.start()` on an `int` which is obviously not allowed.
But you **are** actually executing the function `prints()` as you noticed:

> The thread executes the function function with the argument list args (which must be a tuple).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python) SO question might address some of your questions regarding creating and using threads in Python.

Comment: to expand on this, if you want to call start() explicitly, use 
t = threading.Thread(fn, args, kwargs)
t.start()

Comment: Thank you @ASmallShellScript

Comment: Okay. So, according to you, if I return its identifier, it will execute fine? It would be helpful if you could you throw some more light on this. Also, when I comment out t1.start() and t2.start(), the error is gone but I get only i=3 as print. Understandably because thread was not started right?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit yes it will execute fine as long as you don't call `start` like you said. When you remove the `start` it works well for me (the output is not "in order" since the two threads run simultaneously). If you want it to print "in order" then a better option is to use what was suggested in the other comment (creating a thread, starting it and using `join`)

Comment: @Idos : So, how do I return the identifier?

Comment: What do you need the identifier for? You can use [`thread.get_ident`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.get_ident) for that anyways

Comment: Ohhh. Okay. So, using thread is it not possible to see interleaved execution? I'm trying to understand what needs to be done to achieve that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *see*, what happens is interleaved (in your program). You can use either method to achieve this. If you want *sequential* run you might even want to avoid threads because they are best suited for tasks you want done simultaneously :)