# Is there a way to make tkinter execute a command instantly upon opening?

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition

I'm currently just testing an idea for something simple, using the idea of a workout program as an example. I'm very new to python and so this is more of a test than anything. What I want to have happen is open a window with the workout (just a tkinter label) but then passively in the background have a speech recognition command run to catch for the person saying "next". I'm not interested in having people tell me how to make other bits more effcient because I'm aware it's bad.

I'd just like a solution to make the command `SpeechRecognition1` run passively whilst the `"5 pressups"` label is displayed. Is there anyway to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr

def NextWorkout1():
    workout1.destroy()
    Workout2()

def Workout1():
    global workout1

    workout1 = Tk()

    workout1.geometry("300x44")
    workout1.configure(background="lightblue")
    workout1.resizable(0,0)
    workout1.title("Pressups")

    insLabel = Label(workout1, text="5 pressups", fg="red", bg="lightblue", font="Arial 25 bold")
    insLabel.pack()

    workout1.mainloop()


def Workout2():
    global workout2

    workout2 = Tk()
    workout2.geometry("300x50")
    workout2.configure(background="lightblue")
    workout2.resizable(0,0)
    workout2.title("Starjumps")

    insLabel = Label(workout2, text="15 starjumps", fg="red", bg="lightblue", font="Arial 25 bold")
    insLabel.pack()

    workout2.mainloop()

def SpeechRecognition1():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    for i in range(1):
        command = (r.recognize_google(audio))

        if command == "next":
            NextWorkout1()
        else:
            print("hi")

def SpeechRecognition2():
    global WorkoutNumber

    WorkoutNumber = 0
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    for i in range(1):
        command = (r.recognize_google(audio))

        if command == "next":
            NextWorkout2()

        else:
            print("hi")

Workout1()
```

Comment: do you know about threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the after_idle function with your function as the callback function

in this order

```
from threading import Thread

workout1 = Tk()

thread = Thread(target = SpeechRecognition1)
workout1.after_idle(thread.start)

workout1.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added that and now it simply doesn't open the window and instead just goes straight to do SpeechRecognition1(). https://gyazo.com/0017cba5b8145d707a4b13fcbc469697

Comment: use a threaded method, otherwise it will get stuck on line 2

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906014/6471494

Comment: I have edited the answer to contain the threading part. please mark the question complete if its sufficient.

Comment: it says that “thread” has now been referenced before assignment?

Comment: sorry that was silly of me, I updated the code so that it may work.

Comment: I'm still having some problems here, I'm sorry.

https://gyazo.com/d8c2f50e389f1800bfa031239cfe3bbc

Comment: you've gotta edit your function definition to be def SpeechRecognition1():

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I've got my head around the concept of threads now and should be able to work from here! I'll mark this question, thanks a lot!