# python thread: only one Python thread is running

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm working on the webcam using python and opencv, it seems that it lagged between reading the first one and the second one. So I want to use python thread to fix it. Here is my code:

```
from cv2 import *
from threading import Thread, currentThread, activeCount
import numpy as np
webcam_address0="rtsp://192.168.1.109:6554/stream_0"
webcam_address1="rtsp://192.168.1.106:6554/stream_0"
cap0=VideoCapture(webcam_address0)
cap1=VideoCapture(webcam_address1)
count=0
flag_l=False
flag_r=False
def webcam0_read():
    global frame0
    global flag_l
    while 1:
        print('start reading l')
        ret0, frame0 = cap0.read()
        print('l done')
        flag_l=True
def webcam1_read():
    global frame1
    global flag_r
    while 1:
        print('start reading r')
        ret1, frame1 = cap1.read()
        print('r done')
        flag_r=True
t0=Thread(target=webcam0_read())
t0.setDaemon(True)
t0.start()
t1=Thread(target=webcam1_read())
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
while 1:
    print('ready to print!')
    if flag_l==True and flag_r==True:
        frame0=resize(frame0,(640,360))
        frame1=resize(frame1,(640,360))
        imshow("Video Stream0", frame0)
        imshow("Video Stream1", frame1)
        if waitKey(5) == 's':
            path0="~/images/"+str(count)+"l.jpg"
            path1="~/images/"+str(count)+"r.jpg"
            imwrite(path0,frame0)
            imwrite(path1,frame1)
        elif waitKey(5)==27:
            break
```

When I run it, I only got the result like: start reading l

l done

start reading l

l done

start reading l

l done

It seems that the thread t1 is not running. And it never prints "ready to print!".How can I fix it? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Can this not help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python. I can not provide the answer but maybe the threads should start right after each other

Comment: For starters `Thread(target=webcam1_read())` is wrong. The value of the target argument must be a callable object, e.g. a function. What you pass to your threads is the retrun value of a callable, `None` in your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), the `target` argument to the `Thread` constructor is

> the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.

You are passing `webcam0_read()`, which is not a callable. You are actually calling the `webcam0_read` function, which is stuck in its `while` loop and never returning. The rest of the code isn't even executing.

Change your `target` arguments to `webcam0_read` and `webcam1_read`:

```
t0=Thread(target=webcam0_read)
t0.setDaemon(True)
t0.start()
t1=Thread(target=webcam1_read)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
```