# Python - Running Function in Separate Thread, Then Accessing It

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

So I have a Python code running with one very expensive function that gets executed at times on demand, but it's result is not needed straight away (it can be delayed by a few cycles).

```py
def heavy_function(arguments):
    return calc_obtained_from_arguments

def main():
    a = None
    if some_condition:
        a = heavy_function(x)
    else:
        do_something_with(a)
```

The thing is that whenever I calculate the heavy_function, the rest of the program hangs. However, I need it to run with empty `a` value, or better make it know that `a` is being processed separately and thus should not be accessed. How can I move the heavy_function to separate process and keep calling the main function all the time until heavy_function is done executing, then read the obtained a value and use it in main function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Threads in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple queue.

1. Put your `heavy_function` inside a separate process that idles as long as there is no input in the input queue. Use `Queue.get(block=True)` to do so. Put the result of the computation in another queue.
2. Run your normal process with the empty `a`-value and check emptiness of the output queue from time to time. Maybe use `while Queue.empty():` here.
3. If an item becomes available, because your `heavy_function`has finished, switch to a calculation with the value `a` from your output queue.