# For-loop to make a timer shown in a tkinter window, but it doesn't open a window

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter

I am making a timer with a for loop and showing it in a tkinter window, but as I execute the script, there is no pop-up.
It is very probable that there is some error I don't know of, which is probably pretty simple and I don't see it

I tryed to move the for loop within the code to maybe resolve the problem but that was no help.

```
import tkinter
import time
root = tkinter.Tk()
label_1 = tkinter.Label(root, text="Start")
label_1.pack()
for i in range(1, 3600):
    label_1["text"] = i
    time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window will show up after 3600 seconds. Dont wait 3600 seconds to see it, just change change to 5 seconds. The problem is you are doing `label_1["test"] = i` in the main thread, the same as the App. You need to do such task in another thread, otherwise such loop (due to `time.sleep`) will block the Application

```python
import tkinter
import time
root = tkinter.Tk()
label_1 = tkinter.Label(root, text="Start")
label_1.pack()

import threading

def task():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        label_1["text"] = i
        time.sleep(1)

thread = threading.Thread(target = task)
thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python) about **Multi-threading**

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'm going to research the Multi-thread subject. I am no expert and I have never heared of this.