# Refreshing PI Bluetooth Connection via Python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

The Raspberry PI seems to be dropping the connection to *(some?)* paired devices after 5-15 minutes of running a python script.

The Connection can be recreated with this shell command:

```
bluetoothctl
```

But to enter this command, the script would have to be killed and restarted afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**Attention: After testing this approach for a while I found out it didn't fix the problem in general**

**NOT WORKING:**

Although I didn't test running my program for several hours, this seems to do the trick.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import subprocess

def bluetooth_stay_awake():
    """Ping the bluetooth compontent to keep all connections up"""
    thread= Thread(target=(lambda:subprocess.run(["watch", "bluetoothctl"])))
    thread.start()
```

Using the shell command `watch bluetoothctl` is important here, otherwise the `bluetoothctl` process would block you python script.

---

*[Shell Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)* & *[Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)* in Python