# How to play sound with python and no while loop

Tags: python-3.x, audio

I want to play sound through my python script:

I have used win_sound
pyglet
playsound
and pygame but it doesn't want to work.

Is there any way to do this.

the directory is C:Users/Random/Folder/OtherFolder/Sound1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `librosa` for loading audio data and `sounddevice` for playing audio.

Like this:

```
import time
import librosa
import sounddevice as sd


def play_audio(audio_path, sampling_rate=44100):

    audio, sampling_rate = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=sampling_rate)
    
    duration = librosa.core.get_duration(audio, sr=sampling_rate)
    
    # play the audio
    sd.play(audio, sampling_rate)
    # wait until the audio is done playing
    time.sleep(duration)



play_audio('./test.mp3')
```

Moreover, if this function causes the rest of your program to freeze ( because of `time.sleep` ) you need to run the `play_audio` function on a separate `thread` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python).