# How to print in PyQt5 GUI program while the main window is running?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

Currently i am working on a GUI program in PyQt5. My program has several steps which run after each other. After finish each step i want to print for example `Step1 finished` and then `Step2 finished` and so on. Since the main window freezes the `print` does not work.
It would be very helpful if you give me some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) based solution, where you set an event flag after finishing the task:

```
import threading


done_flag = threading.Event()

def print_status():
    while True:
        done_flag.wait()
        print("I'm done!")
        done_flag.clear()
```

Inside your function, you have to call .set_flag. This functions blocks until your function have finished (if you always call set_flag).

It's by the way always good practice to use threads in GUI applications. This avoids freezing cause the main loop etc. cannot run.

By the way, instead of raw printing, I would suggest using [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) which gives more useful information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Since i am not much familiar with threads, where should i put .set_flag ? for example i have a function to sum up two numbers. In which part should i put .set_flag and when should i use print_status() function?

Comment: Can you please help me how can i put my main function in a thread and other parts in other thread?

Comment: Take a look at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python

Your main function shouldn't be a in a own thread. Otherwise pyqt will freez (can't find the source right now). You could spawn your threads before you call the main loop or after an event (like pressing a button).

set_flag can be called after each function has finished it's calculation, to signal that print can be called.